# Will "anonymous" cookies be available after authentication?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, httpcookie

I have a basic question about cookies.  Here's the scenario:

- An anonymous user browses public pages of my site
- On each page, I add or update a cookie
- The user then authenticates and continues to browse the site
- Root domain will be the same for anonymous and authenticated users

*My question:* Will the cookies set prior to authentication be available to the application after the user has authenticated?

Thanks.

Comment: As long a the name of the cookie you are using in anon mode does not conflict with the name of the cookie used for handling the authentication, you should have no problems. Do you have problems?

Comment: I actually _want_ to access the same cookie in both anon and authenticated modes.   Trying to track page requests when a user is and is not logged in (for this use case, we can assume only one user of the client browser).   No problems yet, working on design :)